# User / Application specific values in Twisted .tac file

Tags: twisted, twistd

What's the best practice for putting additional configuration items, specific to my application, in a twistd ".tac" file? How do I access these items from inside my class?

Is there some property in the "application" object that's intended to store these?

Answer (score 2):

Create your own `twisted.application.service.IService` implementation (by subclassing `twisted.application.service.Service` or just by implementing the correct methods and attributes on a class all of your own).  Give this class an `__init__` that accepts the application-specific parameters.  Launch the rest of your application logic in the `startService` method that is automatically called when `twistd` starts the reactor (for all `IService` objects attached to `application`).  Use the objects you passed to `__init__` in `startService` to get your application going in the right direction.

For example, see the [FingerService](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tutorial/style.html) defined in one of the Twisted tutorials (but unlike that tutorial, don't define all your classes in the `.tac` file!  define them in modules and import them into the `.tac` file).